# Spark unit tests with hive on local metastore

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, datanucleus

I'm using spark 2.2.0, and I would like to create unit tests for spark with hive support.
The test should relay on a metastore that is stored on the local disk (as explained in the [programming guide](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#hive-tables))

I define the session in the following way:

```
val spark = SparkSession
 .builder
 .config(conf)
 .enableHiveSupport()
 .getOrCreate()
```

the creation of the spark session fails with the error:

`org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusUserException: Persistence process has been specified to use a ClassLoaderResolver of name "datanucleus" yet this has not been found by the DataNucleus plugin mechanism. Please check your CLASSPATH and plugin specification.`

I managed to work around this error by adding the following dependency:

`"org.datanucleus" % "datanucleus-accessplatform-jdo-rdbms" % "3.2.9"`

This is strange to me, since this library is already included in spark.

Is there another way to solve this? 
I wouldn't wan't to keep track of the library and update it with every new spark version.